# Given sequence of data(start location, end location) representing bookings for a single cab, find the optimal non breaking sequence

Tags: algorithm, sorting, graph-algorithm, scheduling, greedy

I have been trying to solve an optimization problem but could not able to think it through for any efficient solution.
Here's the problem

> We are given data representing a sequence of bookings on a single car. Each booking data consist of two points (start location, end location). Now given two adjacent bookings b1,b2, we say a relocation is required between those bookings **if the end location of b1 not equal to the start location of b2**
>
> We have to design an algorithm that takes a sequence of bookings as
>   input and outputs a single permutation of the input that minimizes the
>   total number of relocations within the sequence.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Here's my approach
To me, it looks like one of the greedy scheduling problems but I'm not able to derive any good heuristics to solve this problem from any of the existing scheduling problems. At last, I thought of sorting the given sequence on the basis of the minimum difference between start time and end time of the two adjacent sequence using insertion sort.

So, for our given problem 
`[(23, 42),(77, 45),(42, 77)]` will get sorted to
 `[(23, 42),(42, 77),(77, 45)]` thus minimizing end point my start point.

Let's take another example

`[(3,1),(1,3),(3,1),(2,2),(3,1),(2,3),(1,3),(1,1),(3,3),(3,2),(3,3)]`

now after sorting till index 7 using insertion sort, our array will look like

> [**(3,1),(1,3),(3,1),(2,2),(2,3),(3,3),(3,1),(1,3)**,(3,3),(3,2),(3,3)]

Now for placing point (3,3) present at index 8 in the unsorted array we will do the following

> The idea is to put each point in its correct location. For the point
>   (3,3) at index 8 I will search in the already sorted array the first
>   entry whose endpoint matches 3 i.e. starting point of this new point,
>   given the condition that adding this point after that first found
>   entry does not violate the variant that start of next entry should
>   match the end of this point. So, we inserted (3,3) in between (2,3)
>   and (3,1) at index. It looks like this
>
> [(3,1),(1,3),(3,1),(2,2),**(2,3),(3,3),(3,1)**,(1,3),(3,3),(3,2),(1,1)]

However, I'm not sure how will I prove that this is the optimal or not optimal solution. Any pointer is highly appreciated. Is there a better way which I'm sure there is which will help us solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert this easily into a graph problem.

[a, b] -> vertices a and b with an edge between a and b. Use DFS to find all connected components in this undirected graph and do some post processing.

It is linear in input size.

Comment: To be honest I even thought about converting it to graph and doing some traversal but I just don't see how will I ever be able to come up with the sequence since there will be self-loops. Like in this example `[(3,1),(1,3),(3,1),(2,2),(3,1),(2,3),(1,3),(1,1),(3,3),(3,2),(3,3)]` point (1,1) will have a self loop. I couldn't think of any post or pre-processing technique which will help me get the desired sequence